# Updating <video> time based on <input type="range"> click

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'm using the below code to try and update the `currentTime` attribute of a HTML5 `video` with a specified time based on where the user clicks on the `seekBar`. However, what I have is instead just adding the current video time, rather than that selected by the `seekBar` click. Do I have my calculations wrong in the `time` variable? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<video id="video" src="videourl.com" preload></video>
<input id="seek-bar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.05">


// Vars 
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var seekBar = document.getElementById('seek-bar');

// Create clickable seek bar and update video position
seekBar.on('input change', function() {

    // Calculate the new time
    var time = video[0].duration * (seekBar.value / 100);

    // Update the video time
    video[0].currentTime = time;
});
```

Comment: I do not see an `id="video"` in your snippet

Comment: Also `getElementById()` does not return an array.  So `video[0]` is invalid.

Comment: `seekBar` is not a jQuery object, so it should be `$(seekBar).on(...)`

Comment: The calculation looks good. All the rest, not. It's actually should throw some errors. Just test it some playground such as https://jsbin.com and open the console. Maybe it will help you understand what's exactly the problems..

Comment: @moshfeu thanks, are you able to help untangle please? It’s a bit beyond my scope of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of mistakes to OP code (as per comments). It looks as if it was jQuery and there was an attempt to convert it to JavaScript? If so then:

> ```
> ....on('input change',...
> ```

`.on()` is a jQuery method which does not exist use on-event property or `.addEventListener()`

Dereferencing with `[0]` or `.get(0)` is needed to reference a plain JavaScript Object from an jQuery Object so it isn't needed.

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Reference the <form>
const uix = document.forms.uix;
// Register the <form> to input event
uix.oninput = userInterface;

/*
--Callback pases the Event Object
- Reference the <video>
- Reference the clicked, inputed, changed, etc element
- Collect all <form> controls (<input><output><fieldset>)

- If the <input> matches by it's id #seek...
- Calculate the relative values of the #seek and #vid
- #vid Pause() Set currentTime to the value of #seek
- update output#view to value of #seek
*/
function userInterface(e) {
  const vid = document.getElementById('vid');
  const tgt = e.target;
  const view = this.elements.view;

  if (tgt.matches('#seek')) {
    const time = vid.duration * (tgt.valueAsNumber * 0.01);
    vid.pause();
    vid.currentTime = time;
    vid.play();
    view.value = tgt.value;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
     :root {
      font: 700 5vh/1 Consolas
    }
    
    fieldset {
      width: fit-content;
      margin: 2vh auto;
      padding: 1px
    }
    
    video {
      display: block;
      width: 50vw;
      height: auto;
      ,
      margin-bottom: 0
    }
    
    input,
    output {
      font: inherit;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 10vh;
      line-height: 10vh;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    output {
      width: 25%
    }
    
    input {
      width: 60%;
      margin: 0 0 -25px 25px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
,1--CSS goes here-->
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form id='uix'>
    <fieldset>

      <video id='vid' src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005610.mp4" preload></video>

      <input id="seek" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.05">
      <output id='view' for='seek'></output>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
    <!-- JavaScript goes here-->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```